# Softlayer VM with 128GB Memory

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Is it possible that I apply for a Softlayer virtual guest with 128GB memory? I understand we can do that using Bare Metals, but we need some automation that Virtual Guests provide, and therefore we expect those virtual guests have this amount of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the Virtual Guest with 128 GB of RAM will be available very soon, anyway you can submit a ticket for asking or get more information about it.